# How do I auto fill combo boxes? java

Tags: java, combobox

Ok so say I'm doing an event scheduler and i have 3 combo boxes, first combo box is the month, the second is the date, and the third is the year. Is it possible using the Date Object in Java to have it automatically fill the options that you can select from?

Answer (score 1):

The DateFormatSymbols class can be used to get the names of months you can use to fill in the combobox.

`String months[]=(new DateFormatSymbols()).getMonths();`

Don't forget that Java's months start with 0=January

The Calendar class can be used to determine the number of days in a given month, as well as the current year.

`Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance()
cal.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() );
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
int days=cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use Date object to do that? if your goal is to fill all the months, days and several years in combo boxes then you can just add them directly in JCombo by using `combo.addItem("<string value")`. Hope this helps...

Comment: I want to be able for it to use the system time to do such

Comment: so if I get you correctly, you want to be able to make a calendar out of these three combo-boxes which get the d/m/y from the current date and populate in the combos? Which means at any time, there would be only one value in each combo box?

Answer (score 0):

yes that possible, but that will be too hard job to synchronize all three JComboBoxes correctly for valid Year + Month + Day

if not Custom JCalendar ([suggestion from your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935255/how-do-i-make-a-calendar-in-a-standalone-java-gui)), then maybe [JSpinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935255/how-do-i-make-a-calendar-in-a-standalone-java-gui)